# passing parameters to jquery function

Tags: jquery, parameters

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pid1").click(function () {
        $(this).hide(SpeedEnteredByUser);
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<p id = "pid1">This is paragraph</p>
</body>
```

I want to call jquery hide function when paragraph is clicked. But I want to pass the speed(i.e. slow/fast) which is entered by the user. How it can be achieved ?
Here **SpeedEnteredByUser** is the value entered by the user(using some form) and I want to pass this value to hide function.

Comment: How does the user select the speed ? is it an input ? or select ? does the user enter a number ? to the words `slow / fast` etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.val()` jQuery method to get the value of a text input (which should hold your speed value!)

```
$(this).hide(parseInt($("#hide_speed").val(),10));
```

**[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** is used to make sure the value of the input is indeed a number. The function accepts 2 arguments, the value itself, and a radix value to validate against (10 means decimal numbers, 2 means binary, 16 means hexa etc).

It's also possible to do with `<select>`s and other types of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

fix your ID selector and use value of form element through val() function

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pid1").click(function () {
            $(this).hide(parseInt($("#youtextinput").val(),10));
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body>
    <p id = "pid1">This is paragraph</p>
    <input type="text" id="youtextinput"/>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague ... but here goes ... to enable the user to select a speed add this to your HTML :

```
<select id="UserSelectedSpeed">
  <option value="slow">Slow</option>
  <option value="fast">Fast</option>
</select>
```

then do the following :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pid1").click(function () {
        $(this).hide($('#UserSelectedSpeed').val());
    });
});
```

`$('#UserSelectedSpeed').val()` gets the currently selected value from the `select` list.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwvY3/)